# Stack error using commands in argument

Tags: graphics, errors

I want to add figures into my dissertation, and alot of them will have the same need to be cropped. So I wanted to use the trim function of includegraphics. However, because the number of figures will be close around 200-300. If I later change the trim amount, I don't have to have to change the values for every figure. So instead I want something like trim= \A \B \C \D so that I have a \newcommand that can change the trim in the preamble. But I get a runaway argument error, which seems to indicate it is not interpreting the 4 commands together correctly. Anyone have a work around on this? Figure name is unimportant, so use any for testing.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\trimA}{ 4mm }
\newcommand{\trimB}{ 5mm }
\newcommand{\trimC}{ 6mm }
\newcommand{\trimD}{ 7mm }

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.40\linewidth,trim=\trimA \trimB \trimC \trimD]    {DSG31}
\caption{A Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the trim occur before or after the scale?

Comment: `trim={\trimA} {\trimB} {\trimC} {\trimD}` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useless to have spaces in the definition of `\trimA` and siblings, as the spaces should separate the four dimensions before macro expansion is performed.

Just brace the macros.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\trimA}{4mm}
\newcommand{\trimB}{5mm}
\newcommand{\trimC}{6mm}
\newcommand{\trimD}{7mm}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[clip,width=0.40\linewidth,trim={\trimA} {\trimB} {\trimC} {\trimD}]{example-image}
\caption{A Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Accepted for being first to answer, although answer below is a bit more detailed. I figured it had to do with how it interpreted the four commands, so the braces is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of the problem is that from a LaTeX parsing point of view, `\trimA \trimB \trimC \trimD` has no spaces between the dimensions.  One must add a space between the dimensions, here with `\trimA{} \trimB{} \trimC{} \trimD{}` to get it to be digested properly.

I have little experience with the `trim` option myself, but it appears that it just adjusts the bounding box without actually clipping the image.  Thus, in the example below, because the image has no border to trim, the trim just makes the 2nd image look larger. (see below for a remedy)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\trimA}{ 4mm }
\newcommand{\trimB}{ 5mm }
\newcommand{\trimC}{ 6mm }
\newcommand{\trimD}{ 7mm }

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.40\linewidth]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=0.40\linewidth,trim=\trimA{} \trimB{} \trimC{} \trimD{}]{example-image}
\caption{A Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one actually wanted the original image clipped, then this addition of `\clipbox` should help.  EDITED to place the effect in a macro named `\Includegraphics[]{}` (capital "I"):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,trimclip}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\trimA}{ 28mm }
\newcommand{\trimB}{ 15mm }
\newcommand{\trimC}{ 6mm }
\newcommand{\trimD}{ 7mm }

\newcommand\Includegraphics[2][]{%
  \clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{%
  \includegraphics[#1,trim=\trimA{} \trimB{} \trimC{} \trimD{}]{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.40\linewidth]{example-image}

\Includegraphics[width=0.40\linewidth]{example-image}

\Includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now I have two similar ways to fix the issue. Your answer is just a bit different in where you put the { and }. As for your issue with the image sizes, I didn't include it in the MWE, but you need crop=true as well. So \includegraphics[.4\linewidth,trim= \trimA{} \trimB{} \trimC{} \trimD{}, crop=true]{filename} to get the image to crop correctly and truly remove the whitespace.

Comment: @user2103050 I have to admit egreg's answer is superior.  However, this approach might still have virtue if the scale is to be applied prior to the clip (not the usual case).